# Convert Long to Byte [] in android by same result in c#

Tags: c#, android, arrays

I want to convert a long value to a byte array in my android app. my app must convert this value to byte[] by same result when i convert it in C# ! but in android i got (-) number for large number !
I search in net for this problem and found many ways to Only convert long to byte[] but never found anything about this problem

Long value : `47063350`

C# value:

```
[0] 0   byte
[1] 0   byte
[2] 0   byte
[3] 0   byte
[4] 2   byte
[5] 206 byte
[6] 33  byte
[7] 54  byte
```

Android value :

```
[0] = 0
[1] = 0
[2] = 0
[3] = 0
[4] = 2
[5] = -50
[6] = 33
[7] = 54
```

206 now is -50.

My convert method :

```
...
    public static final  int FLAG_JAVA = 0;
    public static final int FLAG_REVERSE = -1;
...
    public static byte[] getBytes(long i, int flag) {
        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        switch (flag) {
            case BitConverter.FLAG_JAVA:
                b[0] = (byte) ((i >> 56) & 0xff);
                b[1] = (byte) ((i >> 48) & 0xff);
                b[2] = (byte) ((i >> 40) & 0xff);
                b[3] = (byte) ((i >> 32) & 0xff);
                b[4] = (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0xff);
                b[5] = (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0xff);
                b[6] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xff);
                b[7] = (byte) ((i >> 0) & 0xff);
                break;
            case BitConverter.FLAG_REVERSE:
                b[7] = (byte) ((i >> 56) & 0xff);
                b[6] = (byte) ((i >> 48) & 0xff);
                b[5] = (byte) ((i >> 40) & 0xff);
                b[4] = (byte) ((i >> 32) & 0xff);
                b[3] = (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0xff);
                b[2] = (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0xff);
                b[1] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xff);
                b[0] = (byte) ((i >> 0) & 0xff);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Did you `Debugging` it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing a problem between Signed Byte & Unsigned Byte

for your android value, you get a signed byte which is -50, so if you want make it unsigned, here is a solution:

```
public static byte signedToUnsigned(byte signed){
    return signed & 0xff;
}
```

after signedToUnsigned, you will get 206 instead of -50.